# hdfs dfs -mkdir, No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hi I am new to hadoop and trying to create directory in hdfs called twitter_data.
I have set up my vm on softlayer, installed & started hadoop successfully.

This is the commend I am trying to run:

> hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Hadoop/twitter_data

And it keeps returning this error message:

```
 /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: ./hadoop-env.sh: Permission denied
16/10/19 19:07:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Hadoop/twitter_data': No such file or directory
```

Why does it say there is no such file and directory? I am ordering it to make directory, shouldn't it just create one? I am guessing it must be the permission issue, but I cant resolve it. Please help me hdfs experts. I have been spending too much time on what seems to be a simple matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, and I want to be able to view this hdfs on my browser. How can I access it?

Comment: I tried 
`hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/Hadoop/twitter_data`, and I get this 
`/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: ./hadoop-env.sh: Permission denied
16/10/19 19:25:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Call From master.someplace.net/198.23.84.123 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`
I need to be able to see this on my browser.

Comment: btw, can anybody explain to me what the difference is between just creating a directory vs. having hdfs://localhost:9000 in front? 

I saw examples for both cases. and I just assumed hdfs://localhost:9000 makes is accessible via browser. please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is because the parent directories do not exist yet either.  Try `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/Hadoop/twitter_data`.  The `-p` flag indicates that all nonexistent directories leading up to the given directory are to be created as well.

As for the question you posed in the comments, simply type into your browser `http://<host name of the namenode>:<port number>/`.

Comment: Thank you . I tried it, and I got this error message `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: ./hadoop-env.sh: Permission denied`

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks, its always permission issue! Solved it

Answer (score 11):

use the below steps command to create the directory:

1) don't run the hadoop and format the namenode:-

```
$ hadoop namenode -format
```

2) run hadoop by :-

```
$ start-all.sh
```

3)now first make the initial directory then create the another in same directory:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/Hadoop
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/Hadoop/tweeter_data
```

Follow the above steps to solve the problem.